# Select second tag

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors

How can I select the second `<a>` tag from the following snippet?

```
<div class="hovno">
    <a href='...'></a>
    <a href='...'></a>
</div>
```

I know that I can find the first `<a>` tag by using:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.hovno a")
```

But I don't know how to select the second `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always find all direct `a` children and get the second element:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.hovno > a")[1]
```

Or, according to the example, the last element would work too:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.hovno > a")[-1]
```

---

[`nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-of-type) pseudo-class is also an option:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.hovno > a:nth-of-type(2)")
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `nth-of-type`

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.hovno a:nth-of-type(2)");
```

Answer (score -1):

Im no sure but try this

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.hovno").find_element_by_tag_name('a')[2]